# How to make text inside a button scale horizontally to page?

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, scaling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGcAv.png)Text inside button is extending outside of the button. Is there anyways I can make the text scale based on the button/screen size? I already tried doing auto and searching youtube and google. Also used media query.

I already tried doing auto and searching youtube and google.

```
@media(min-width: 400px) {
    .purplebutton {
        min-width: 350px;
    }
    .buttontext {
        font-size: 16px;

    }
}
@media(min-width: 600px) {
    .purplebutton {
        min-width: 450px;
    }
    .buttontext {
        font-size: 17px;

    }
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
    .purplebutton {
        min-width: 550px;

    }
    .buttontext {
        font-size: 20px;

    }
}
```

Expected result is the text to fit inside the button and size of font adjust according.

Actual result is the text extends outside the button

Comment: can you add html/jsx for the elements that are having a problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using absolute scaling units (`px`) for `font-size` use relative scaling font-size such as `em`, `rem` or `vw`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using word-break property to the button like this
**word-break: break-all;**